# Filtering with more than one parameter in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I am working on an odata fiori app & I want to filter my list depending on two parameters and not just one : "Mpobj" & "Atinn", so i tried this code :

```
    _onObjectMatched: function(oEvent) {
    var sObjectPath = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").infosId;
    var sObjectPath1 = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").objectI;
        var oView = this.getView();
        oView.bindElement(sObjectPath, sObjectPath1);
        var frag = this.getView().byId("tableid1");
        var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Mpobj", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sObjectPath);
        var oFilter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Atinn", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sObjectPath1);
        frag.bindElement("Infos" + "/mesureSet").getBinding("items").filter([oFilter], [oFilter1]);
    },
```

But when i debugg, it appears that he's reading the first parameter "Mpobj" but doesn't recognize the second one "Atinn".

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use just one array. Try the following

```
var aFilters=[];
var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Mpobj", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sObjectPath);
aFilters.push(oFilter);
var oFilter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Atinn", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sObjectPath1);
aFilters.push(oFilter1);

frag.bindElement("Infos" + "/mesureSet").getBinding("items").filter(aFilters);
```